# ingore Enter（line break） when read data from text file in C language

Tags: c, enter

I'm reading some data from a file "test1.txt",everything is ok but when encounter the Enter(line break),it gives me the answer I don't want

code and file:

**main.c**:

```
#include "fscan.h"
#include <stdio.h>
 
int main(){
    float lstm_val;
    int row;
    int col;
    float dense[2][4];
    FILE *fp = fopen("test1.txt","r");
    for (row = 0; row < 2; row++){
        for (col = 0; col < 4; col++){
            lstm_val = fscan(fp);
            dense[row][col] = lstm_val;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**fscan.c**:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXCN 50

float fscan(FILE *fp)
{   //FILE* lstm_txt = NULL;
    char lstm_weight[MAXCN] = {0};
    int lstm = 0;
    int i = 0;
    float lstm_val;
    
    while ((i + 1 < MAXCN) && ((lstm = fgetc(fp)) != ' ')  && (lstm != EOF)){
        lstm_weight[i++] = lstm;
    }
    printf("\n lstm_weight: %s\n\n", lstm_weight);
    lstm_val = atof(lstm_weight);
    printf("\n convert \"lstm_weight\" to lstm_val is : %f\n\n", lstm_val);
    return lstm_val;
 }
```

**fscan.h**:

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern float fscan(FILE *fp);
```

**test1.txt**:

```
4.217959344387054443e-01 -2.566376626491546631e-01 2.173236161470413208e-01 4.217959344387054443e-01
2.173236161470413208e-01 4.217959344387054443e-01 4.217959344387054443e-01 -2.566376626491546631e-01
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgcWA.png)
between the "4.217959344387054443e-01" in the last one in the first line and "2.173236161470413208e-01" in the 1st one in the second line is a Enter, obviously ,the result is wrong when encounter this Enter

the result is :

```
 lstm_weight: 4.217959344387054443e-01


 convert "lstm_weight" to lstm_val is : 0.421796


 lstm_weight: -2.566376626491546631e-01


 convert "lstm_weight" to lstm_val is : -0.256638


 lstm_weight: 2.173236161470413208e-01


 convert "lstm_weight" to lstm_val is : 0.217324


 lstm_weight: 4.217959344387054443e-01
2.173236161470413208e-01


 convert "lstm_weight" to lstm_val is : 0.421796


 lstm_weight:


 convert "lstm_weight" to lstm_val is : 0.000000


 lstm_weight: 4.217959344387054443e-01


 convert "lstm_weight" to lstm_val is : 0.421796


 lstm_weight: 4.217959344387054443e-01


 convert "lstm_weight" to lstm_val is : 0.421796


 lstm_weight: -2.566376626491546631e-01


 convert "lstm_weight" to lstm_val is : -0.256638
```

How can I avoid it?

Comment: `while ((i + 1 < MAXCN) && ((lstm = fgetc(fp)) != ' ')  && lstm != '\n' && (lstm != EOF))`?? Just add the check `lstm != '\n'`.

Comment: Note, you should also avoid using `atof()` or `atoi()`, etc. in actual code. The provide zero error checking on the conversion and will happily accept `atof ("my cow");` returning `0` without any indication of error. Instead use `strtof()` (or at minimum `sscanf()` -- which would also eliminate your need to check `lstm != '\n'`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was about the write the solution but kudos to Mr. Rankin, he explain well. It is regarding with the escape sequences. For example Enter is actually \n where all those required for computer to understand and display it for you in a Newline(\n) or Tab(\t).
Check this for more information : [Wikipedia - Table of Escapes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C#Table_of_escape_sequences)

If there is anything require omitting, such as , you have to implement it lstm != ',' .
This is sometimes used in readability 42,376.98(forty-two-thousand-three-hundred-seventy-six-point-nine-eight) for example

Final code will be

```
while ((i + 1 < MAXCN) && ((lstm = fgetc(fp)) != ' ') && (lstm != '\n') && (lstm != EOF))
```

Check David C. Rankin answer and also wikipedia link for escape sequences.
More about :

- [String To Float](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtof/)
- [String To Double](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtod/)

Also, the [Linux man pages online (man7.org)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/index.html) can provide the proper usage for any standard function you may encounter.

Comment: Thank you for the attribution, nicely done. Wikipedia and cplusplus.com are reasonably outside references, but be wary of using others (many are just plain wrong) I'll reformat your links for you this time `:)`

Comment: Dear Mr.Rankin, appericated your edit and comment. It looks better with the formatting. Also I apologise to re-post an answer. You found the solution first. I just wanted to make it clear for OP that the reason to '\n(Newline Escape Sequence)'.

Comment: More than happy to have you help post it. Welcome to StackOverflow.